# MsBuild cannot load NHibernate on TFS

Tags: sqlite, tfs, nuget-package, mstest, ravendb

Hi I have a set of MsTest tests that runs with NHibernate, SQLLite.
I can succesfully load the assemblies from any DEV machine and run the tests.
On TFS we have a drop folder where we put all the assemblies and a copy of MsTest.exe, where we run the unit tests from.
The problem I get on TFS is the following:

> Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
>   Type is not resolved for member 'NHibernate.HibernateException,NHibernate,
>   Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'..

But this assembly and the related dependencies are copied to the drop location, so I don't understand why MsTest can't load this assembly. 
I run the tests using this command in MsBuild:

```
mstest /testcontainer:"mydll.dll" /detail:errormessage /detail:errorstacktrace
```

But unfortunately I can't see the real error, I guess it is related to SQLLite.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but perhaps the `NHibernate` version used by the application under test and the `MSTest` are not the same. So, `MSTest` tries to load a different version of the dll, which is not there.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that's not the case, I checked and the version is the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSTest exception: Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Type is not resolved for member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085140/mstest-exception-unit-test-adapter-threw-exception-type-is-not-resolved-for-me)

Comment: @Raffaeu did you resolve this issue? got the same atm..

Comment: Yes, actually the problem was with RavenDB and other Nuget packages that were loading a different version of NHibernate. You should check that cause some Nugets embed NHibernate in it